# Regional formats on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, system-settings

Where are the regional formats on Ubuntu taken/supplied from?

There is no such format as "Hindi, Fiji" so that should not be on there [image: screenshot] or anywhere.

As a former British colony, the country Fiji (mostly) uses the Australian format.

Comment: I believe it's from https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php  , though wikipedia is probably easier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes providing a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fijian_language which is what your picture selection I believe relates to.

Comment: "mostly"  being the key part. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiji_Hindi